# How to write proper react code for usercontrol?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building "usercontrols" with reactJS and a method that renders a part might look something like this :

```
var FeedTopic = React.createClass({
        render: function() {

            return (
                <div className="topic">
                    <div className="tUImgLnk">
                        <a title={this.props.data.UserName} target="_blank" href={this.props.data.UserInfoUrl}>
                            <img className="tUImg" src={this.props.data.UserPicSrc} />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="tInfo">
                        <div className="tName">
                            <a title={this.props.data.UserName} target="_blank" href={this.props.data.UserInfoUrl}>{this.props.data.UserName}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="tTime">
                            <span>{this.props.data.DateCreated}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
});
```

The problem is that I dont finde a easy way to hide/show specific elements easy. It does not work to put if statements in the return. I could write something like this :

```
var GridRow = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            var row;

            row = this.props.cells.map(function(cell, i) {
                if(cell.Data.CellType == 1){
                    if(cell.Data.Text1URL != null && cell.Data.Text1URL.length>0){
                        return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}><a target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text1URL} title={cell.Data.Text1}>{cell.Data.Text1}</a></td>     
                    }
                    else {
                        return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{cell.Data.Text1}</td>
                    }

                }
                else if(cell.Data.CellType == 2){
                    if(cell.Data.IconUrl.length > 0){
                        return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}><a target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.IconUrl} title={cell.Data.Text1}><img alt={cell.Data.Text1} title={cell.Data.Text1} src={cell.Data.IconSrc} /></a></td>
                    }
                    else{
                        return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}><img alt={cell.Data.Text1} title={cell.Data.Text1} src={cell.Data.IconSrc} /></td>
                    }
                }
                else if(cell.Data.CellType == 3){
                    return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>
                                <a className={cell.Data.Text1Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text1URL} title={cell.Data.Text1}>
                                    {cell.Data.Text1}
                                </a><br/>
                                <a className={cell.Data.Text2Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text2URL} title={cell.Data.Text2}>
                                    {cell.Data.Text2}
                                </a>
                            </td>       
                }
                else if(cell.Data.CellType == 4){
                    return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>
                                {cell.Data.Text1}<br/>
                                <a className={cell.Data.Text2Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text2URL} title={cell.Data.Text2}>
                                    {cell.Data.Text2}
                                </a>
                            </td>       
                }

            }.bind(this));

            return (
                <tr>
                    {row}
                </tr>
            );
        }
    });
```

But ut is hard to see what markaup that will really be printed and it would involve a lot of repatativ markup.

Im not sure why it have to be split up in a function and a return. When writing this in ASP.NET MVC the if statements goes right in the markup and there is always only one place to look for how the markup will be printed.

It would look something like this in ASP.NET MVC

```
<div>
  <% if (contition) { %>
     <div class="MyProfile">
        ...
     </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Its clean and simple to follow

Am I doing this the wrong way or is it just the way react is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im not sure why it have to be split up in a function and a return. When writing this in ASP.NET MVC the if statements goes right in the markup and there is always only one place to look for how the markup will be printed.

It's because you're writing JavaScript code, not a template which will be parsed and executed later. JSX is just syntactic sugar for making it nicer to nest tag/component creation vs. the regular function calls it transpiles to.

As a result, you need to put your coding hat on when it comes to organising conditional logic.

For fairly simple logic, nesting `{someArray.map()}` calls and using `{someStatement && <contents>}` and `{someStatement ? <contents> : <alt-contents>}` conditionals can get you most of the way, but in cases like this where you effectively have a switch and some nested conditionals that gets ugly pretty quickly.

It might be less ugly to either pull the logic for rendering each different cell type into a function per type. These could be standalone (since they don't use any references to `this`, methods within the component itself, or even methods in a new `GridRowCell` component, which could itself organise rendering of another component for the actual rendering based on the cell's type should rendering get complicated enough to need complete specialisation.

---

This is what splitting rendering into different methods in the same component might look like:

```
var GridRow = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <tr>
      {this.props.cells.map(function(cell, i) {
        return this['renderCellType' + cell.Data.CellType](cell, i)
      })}
    </tr>
  },

  renderCellType1(cell, i) {
    var contents = cell.Data.Text1
    if (cell.Data.Text1URL) {
      contents = <a target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text1URL} title={cell.Data.Text1}>{contents}</a>
    }
    return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{contents}</td>     
  },

  renderCellType2(cell, i) {
    var contents = <img alt={cell.Data.Text1} title={cell.Data.Text1} src={cell.Data.IconSrc} />
    if (cell.Data.IconUrl) {
      contents = <a target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.IconUrl} title={cell.Data.Text1}>{contents}</a>
    }
    return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>{contents}</td>
  },

  renderCellType3(cell, i) {
    return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>
      <a className={cell.Data.Text1Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text1URL} title={cell.Data.Text1}>
        {cell.Data.Text1}
      </a><br/>
      <a className={cell.Data.Text2Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text2URL} title={cell.Data.Text2}>
        {cell.Data.Text2}
      </a>
    </td>  
  },

  renderCellType4(cell, i) {
    return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>
      {cell.Data.Text1}<br/>
      <a className={cell.Data.Text2Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text2URL} title={cell.Data.Text2}>
        {cell.Data.Text2}
      </a>
    </td>      
  }
});
```

Having done that to get a feel for the logic, it strikes me that a rendered grid row cell consists of 3 distinct parts -  an initial text, linked text, icon or linked icon and a second link which is always the same, with a linebreak between them in cases where the second link should be displayed.

It might be easier to follow/less repitition if you break display logic down along those lines instead of at the top level by cell type.

---

Or a hybrid of inline conditionals and functions only where there's nested conditional logic:

```
var GridRow = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <tr>
      {this.props.cells.map(function(cell, i) {
        var type = cell.Data.CellType
        var multiline = (type == 3 || type == 4)
        return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>
          {type == 1 && this.renderCellType1(cell)}
          {type == 2 && this.renderCellType2(cell)}
          {type == 3 && <a className={cell.Data.Text1Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text1URL} title={cell.Data.Text1}>
              {cell.Data.Text1}
            </a>}
          {type == 4 &&  cell.Data.Text1}
          {multiline && <br/>}
          {multiline && <a className={cell.Data.Text2Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text2URL} title={cell.Data.Text2}>
            {cell.Data.Text2}
           </a>}
        </td>
      })}
    </tr>
  },

  renderCellType1(cell) {
    var contents = cell.Data.Text1
    if (cell.Data.Text1URL) {
      contents = <a target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text1URL} title={cell.Data.Text1}>{contents}</a>
    }
    return contents   
  },

  renderCellType2(cell, i) {
    var contents = <img alt={cell.Data.Text1} title={cell.Data.Text1} src={cell.Data.IconSrc}/>
    if (cell.Data.IconUrl) {
      contents = <a target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.IconUrl} title={cell.Data.Text1}>{contents}</a>
    }
    return contents
  }
})
```

---

Or introducing a new component to make the basic wrapping logic declarative:

```
var Wrap = React.createClass({
  render() {
    if (!!this.props.when) {
      var {when, withTag, ...props} = this.props
      return <this.props.withTag {...props}>{this.props.children}</this.props.withTag>
    }
    else {
      return this.props.children
    }
  }
})

var GridRow = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <tr>
      {this.props.cells.map(function(cell, i) {
        var type = cell.Data.CellType
        return <td className={cell.Meta.HTMLClass} key={i}>
          {type == 1 && <Wrap withTag="a" when={ccell.Data.Text1URL} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text1URL} title={cell.Data.Text1}>
            {cell.Data.Text1}
          </Wrap>}
          {type == 2 && <Wrap withTag="a" when={cell.Data.IconUrl} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.IconUrl} title={cell.Data.Text1}>
            <img alt={cell.Data.Text1} title={cell.Data.Text1} src={cell.Data.IconSrc}/>
          </Wrap>}
          {type == 3 && <a className={cell.Data.Text1Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text1URL} title={cell.Data.Text1}>
            {cell.Data.Text1}
          </a>}
          {type == 4 && cell.Data.Text1}
          {multiline && <br/>}
          {multiline && <a className={cell.Data.Text2Class} target={cell.Data.URLTarget} href={cell.Data.Text2URL} title={cell.Data.Text2}>
            {cell.Data.Text2}
           </a>}
        </td>
      })}
    </tr>
  }
})
```